# How to decode string to object EXTJS 6

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, decode, extjs6

I'm I'm using ExtJS to create a formPanel dynamyc from database (string result from server to object extjs)

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     async : false,
     method : 'POST',
     url : '/Devt/GetFormItemCustomization',
     params : {
        TableName : 'tabeltest',
        col : 1
    },
    success : function (response) {
        var results = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.log(results );
        var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            width : 300,
            bodyPadding : 10,
            renderTo : 'formCustDiv',
            name : "test",
            items : [results]
        });
    }
})
```

**this response from server:**

```
{
   fieldLabel:'Employee Id',
   xtype:'textfield',
   allowBlank:false,
},
{
   fieldLabel:'Nick Name',
   xtype:'textfield',
   allowBlank: false,
}
```

but this only create one object from last data.
**Object**

```
{
   fieldLabel: "Nick Name", 
   xtype: "textfield", 
   allowBlank: false
 }
```

i want response from server decode become two object:

**Object** `{fieldLabel: "Employee Id", xtype: "textfield", allowBlank: false}`

**Object** `{fieldLabel: "Nick Name", xtype: "textfield", allowBlank: false}`

Any suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your server should always return valid JSON. Two objects, comma-separated, isn't valid JSON. (You can check with one of the many online JSON validators if you don't believe me.) Could your server possibly return an array of objects? Like this:

```
[
    {fieldLabel: "Employee Id", xtype: "textfield", allowBlank: false},
    {fieldLabel: "Nick Name", xtype: "textfield", allowBlank: false}
]
```

In that case, you could easily go ahead and create a form from these by removing the array around the `results` variable:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        width : 300,
        bodyPadding : 10,
        renderTo : 'formCustDiv',
        name : "test",
        items : results
    });
```